why don't my tahajjud duas get answered
Nothing works out for me, none of my duas come true. this is one example, I made dua to get high marks in my assessments, got help for it and put in so much effort and still dont get high. one was a group presentation of 3 and one of my members got sick so we thought we wouldnt need to present so I didn't memorise my part fully but on the day we ended up having to present and you know what the marker said, that I was great in the content and answering questions but got marked down because I kept looking at my paper. I was shocked, my group member was the only one out of everyone who couldn't come if none of that happened I would have got so much higher. then I thought its fine ill get good in the exam
I studied but during my exam my brain just stopped working I couldn't think at all couldn't put anything together but I managed to write some stuff but it wasn't enough. I have been praying tahajjud to just pass and then I got my mark and I was off my just 1.6 marks. I couldn't believe it nothing worked none of my tahajjud worked, how could my tahajjud not be enough just to get that 1 mark. Ive been so patient whenever something happens because im like ill get something good but after this I feel like im just living wrong what am I doing wrong how could my tahajjud dua not come true actually it never comes true am I praying tahajjud right?
I start by praying 2 rakat then 1 witr then read the tahajjud dua and start with the normal way of making dua with praising Allah and prophet Muhammad SAW then ask for forgiveness then say my dua then ask for forgiveness again end it with praising again and read the tahajjud dua again

Please do not keep re-asking the same question. Also we are not a personal counseling website.

im not trying to receive counselling just want to know if im praying correctly

Instead of spending that time and energy on Tahajjud( a voluntary effort), why not focus on studying and working toward your goals? It is clear from https://quran.com/en/al-anam/164 that “No one will reap except what they sow” .

thats the thing I did study
